# Objective C category method not recognized in custom class "Cannot find interface declaration"

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, categories

I want to use a custom method in a custom class in my viewcontroller

```
//Viewcontroller.h
#import "Class1.h"

//Class1.h
//#import "Class1+Category.h" // Deemed unnecessary in comments below.
@interface Class1: NSObject
-(void)doSomething;
@end

//Class1.m
#import "Class1.h"
@implementation Class1
-(void)doSomething{
  NSLog("In doSomething");
}
@end
```

Now I want a category method of Class1.

```
//Class1+Category1.h
#import "Class1.h"
@interface Class1  (Category1) // ERROR : Cannot find interface declaration
-(void)doAnotherThing;
@end

//Class1+Category1.m
#import "Class1+Category.h"
@implementation Class1 (Category1)
-(void)doAnotherThing{
  NSLog(@"Did Another thing");
}
@end
```

Finally - in my viewcontroller.m I see the doSomething method, but not the doAnother thing

```
 //viewcontroller.m
 Class1 *myClass1 = [[Class1 alloc]init];
 [Class1 doSomething]; //Works great!
 [Class1 doAnotherThing]; //Not recognized
```

I have added the -all_load to my target settings. I am out of ideas..do I use the @class? I get 'Cannot find interface declaration' error

Comment: Are you sure that #import "Class1+Category.m" should not be #import "Class1+Category.h" ? viewcontroller.m should also import the Category .h

Comment: No, I just edited that.. I was useing dummy values .. My mistake.

Comment: Why is Class1.h importing Class1+Category.h? There is no reason for this.

Comment: Removed the import in the Class1.h, Still the same error and method not recognized..  Will edit question

Comment: But "viewcontroller.m" (or viewcontroller.h) should import "Class1+Category.h", as stated by J_D above.

Comment: CORRECT ANSWER> Martin R, you are my Oprah

Comment: @J_D spotted this first.

Comment: o wow.. I just suck at reading... J_D, you are my Oprah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class and category seems correct at first glance but your controller needs to import Class1+Category.h. Perhaps that's what you missed?